# How to extract a word from a link in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I need to have an optimal code for extracting a word from a HTTPs link which will be a new column created, please let me know the best and fast approach

code :

```
df['new_column'] = url
final_df['currency'] = final_df['currency'].str.replace(r'[a-z]*://[a-z]*.[a-z]*.[a-z]*/[a-z]*/', 
'').str.strip()
```

New column

```
   https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data
   https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data
   https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data
   https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-inr-historical-data
   https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-inr-historical-data
```

Result

```
   usd-jpy
   usd-jpy
   usd-jpy
   usd-inr
   usd-inr
```

Comment: What is the logic for extraction?

Comment: i need only usd-jpy, usd-inr from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new_column'].str.split('/').str[-1].str.split('-').str[:2].str.join('-')
```

Output:

```
usd-jpy
usd-jpy
usd-jpy
usd-inr
usd-inr
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Could you also explain your code once that will be really helpful

Comment: First `split` the `new_column` on `/` and pick the last value. Then split the last value on `-` and pick the first 2 values and join them with `-`.

Comment: @anaghas 
1.) `df['new_column'].str.split('/')` is splitting the string into **['https://www.investing.com', 'currencies', 'usd-jpy-historical-data']**.
2. ) `str[-1].str.split('-')` gets the last element from the above list i.e. **usd-jpy-historical-data** and splits it at hyphen character. Now you get **['usd', 'jpy', 'historical', 'data']**
3. ) `str[:2].str.join('-')` gets the first 2 elements from the list in 2nd step i.e. **usd** and **jpy** and joins them using the hyphen character, thereby giving you the desired result i.e **usd-jpy**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
>>> df["new_column"].str.extract("(?:.*/)*([a-z]*-[a-z]*)")

0  usd-jpy
1  usd-jpy
2  usd-jpy
3  usd-inr
4  usd-inr
```